# Ошибка выполнения запроса к БД. Как упростить запрос в EntityFramework?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

В коде генерируется огромный запрос с множеством методов `Where`, на что вылетает исключение с текстом:

> Обработчику запросов не удалось предоставить план запроса, так как для
>   этого требуется рабочая таблица, а минимальный размер ее строки
>   превышает допустимый максимум в 8060 байт. Типичная причина, по
>   которой требуется рабочая таблица, - наличие в запросе предложений
>   GROUP BY или ORDER BY. Если в запросе присутствует предложение GROUP
>   BY или ORDER BY, рассмотрите возможность уменьшения количества или
>   размера полей в этих предложениях. Рассмотрите возможность
>   использования префикса (LEFT()) или хэширования (CHECKSUM()) полей для
>   группирования или префикса для упорядочивания. Однако следует принять
>   во внимание, что это приведет к изменению поведения запроса.

Подскажите, о чем тут речь и есть ли возможность обойти такое поведение?

Comment: а почему не приводите никакого примера кода, не говоря уже о МВСП ?

Answer (score 0):

Если Where используется в linq, попробуй фильтровать информация при подтягивании из БД с помощью регулярных выражений(пример с MongoDriver - не знаю есть ли в Entity Framework):

```
        bsonArray.Add(new BsonDocument("productCode", new BsonDocument("$eq", ProductCode)));
        var filter = new BsonDocument("$and", bsonArray);
        return _orders.Find(filter).ToList()
```

Вытягивает информацию по определенному коду товара.